# django prepopulated fields break with hyphens

Tags: django, admin, slug

I started putting prepopulated_fields options in my admins and funny stuff started happening
I have this model

```
class Pelicula(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length= 15, unique= True, help_text = "Nombre corto para la URL", primary_key= True)
```

and this in admin.py

```
class PeliculaAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug' : ['nombre']}
```

nothing fancy, it's described all over the place
But as soon as I use this slug in an object_detail generic view, the slug only works if it was only one word to begin with. 
so if i have this view

```
def detalle_pelicula(request, pelicula):
    return list_detail.object_detail(
        request,
        queryset = Pelicula.objects.all(),
        slug = pelicula,
        template_name='sections/detalle_pelicula.html',
        template_object_name = 'pelicula',
        extra_context = extra_context,
        )
```

if the original name had any spaces in it, i get a "No Page matches the given query." error. So detail/test will work but detail/test-page won't
I'm a bit stumped

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253200/hyphens-in-slugfield

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i'm guessing you have your urlconf setup parsing your slug using \w+ try using [-A-Za-z0-9_]+

```
# e.g. in urls.py

url(r'del/(?P<slug>[-A-Za-z0-9_]+)/$',   'person_delete',  name='person_delete'),
```